# OpenLayers events issue, featureover and onselect

Tags: events, openlayers, onselect

I have a strange problem with the use of vector layers events.
Here is snipped of my code:

```
var options = {
                    projection : "EPSG:3857",
                    displayProjection : "EPSG:4326",
                    numZoomLevels : 18,
             //after delete this part below of option everything works good
                     eventListeners: {
                         featureover: function(e) {
                         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="ok';
               }}};
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

w_parcels = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("PARCELS", {
                                            styleMap : style_parcels,
                                            projection : "EPSG:3857",
                                            strategies : [ new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed() ],
                                            protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                                            url : "parcels.php",
                                            format : new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()})
                                            });


    map.addLayers([osm,w_parcels]);

    selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(w_parcels, {
                        clickout: false,
                        multiple: true,
                        onSelect : onFeatureSelect,
                        onUnselect : onFeatureUnselect,
                        toggleKey: "ctrlKey" // ctrl key removes from selection
                    });

    selectControl.handlers.feature.stopDown = false;
    map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());

    function onFeatureSelect(feature) {
            console.log('it works');
        }
```

In this code event **onselect** dosen't work always when I click on feature on the layer(sometimes I have to do double click).

If I delete **eventListeners** from **options** , the **onselect** works perfect, I mean always when I click feature on the layer.

What is wrong in my code? Is the possibility to resolve this conflict betwween **eventListeners** an **onselect**?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like, Event `featureover` masks the select control as that function will executes first while you `select`, as you must mouse over the Vector Layer for clicking it. But if the functionality is limited to `select` and `mouse-over` vector layer. Then you can use something like-

```
 eventListeners: {
    featureover: function(e) {
      //behavior for hover events
    },
    featureout: function(e) {
      //behavior for mouse out events
    },                    
    featureclick: function(e) {
      //behavior for click events
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe it could be a good solve but i have all logic application using onselect where all is connected with tables etc. and using information about pressed keys ctrl, shift,  measure area and distance. It could be dificult change everything of it:( Thank you again for interest my problem.